# how do I do sscanf in c#

Tags: c#, c

how do I do this in C#?

```
int a,b,c;
sscanf(astring,"%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
```

minimal code and dependencies is preferable, is there some built in regex stuff?

I'm using c# 4.0

Comment: **sscanf Equivalents in C#** <br>
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188759.aspx

Comment: Use Regex.Match(). Better control of field parsing as well and a lot less of the strange behaviors that plague scanf().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If like scannf you are willing to assume that users will give completely correct data then you can do the following.

```
string astring = ...;
string[] values = astring.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int a = Int32.Parse(values[0]);
int b = Int32.Parse(values[1]);
int c = Int32.Parse(values[2]);
```

Regular expressions would work for this scenario but they are a bit overkill.  The string can easily be tokenized with the aforementioned Split method.

Comment: I assume that StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries option would effectively allow any number of spaces to separate the entries?

Comment: Now if only we could do `a, b, c = astring.Split(' ', ...).Select(Int32.Parse);`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I can come up with is this:

```
var fields = astring.Split(null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
a = int.Parse(fields[0]);
b = int.Parse(fields[1]);
c = int.Parse(fields[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, it's fairly straight forward to write your own version of `sscanf()` in C#. The syntax makes it reasonably easy to implement.

I implemented my own version and posted on the web. You can view it [here](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-sscanf-replacement-for-net).